# While running doxygen, "sh: doxypy: command not found" error is coming

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell, doxygen

I have installed `doxygen 1.8.8` on my linux machine, and trying to run `doxypy` but seeing issue with it

```
[nipatel@caspgval4 docs]$ doxygen --version
1.8.8

[nipatel@caspgval4 docs]$ whereis doxypy
doxypy: /usr/bin/doxypy.py

[nipatel@caspgval4 docs]$ which doxypy
doxypy: Command not found.
```

While running doxygen, I see following error:

```
Reading /mypath/myfile.py...
sh: doxypy: command not found
```

PATH on the machine:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin/doxypy.py
```

Can someone let me know if I am missing anything here? How can I make doxypy command work? Do I need to add any `PATH` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to not rename `doxypy.py` to `doxypy`.

Create a symbolic link: `ln -s /usr/bin/doxypy.py /usr/bin/doxypy`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your `$PATH` variable doesn't contain the default paths? `echo $PATH` should give something like:

`[root@server ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin`

If it's empty, You may set the `PATH` variable with this command

`export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"`

Comment: @ Nikhil, I have updated the question with my path, is it correct? or I need to update it?

Comment: Looks fine..lets hit go and see

Comment: Dint help, `$ doxypy
doxypy: Command not found.`, it doesn't recognize the command.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed `/usr/bin/doxypy.py` to `/usr/bin/doxypy` and it resolved the issue.